# Graph models problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

10 children and 17 adults split into teams, say that they cooperated for a project with 2 children and 3 adults. Do they all tell the truth?
Clarifying each adult i claims to have worked with three other distinct adults and two other distinct children, and each child a claims to have worked with three distinct adults and two other distinct children

Comment: What are the constraints on the problem?

Comment: @DavidKleiman There are no constraints.

Comment: Can they all be working on more than 1 project? What does it even mean for them to be working on a project?

Comment: @DavidKleiman They all worked on the same project and they all say that they cooperated with 2 children and 3 adults

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Your edit does not help with clarity. Let me try to clarify: each adult $i$ claims to have worked with three other distinct adults and two other distinct children; and each child $a$ claims to have worked with three distinct adults and two other distinct children. Is this correct?

Comment: @ml0105 Correct. I used your comment in my question.

Comment: Fantastic! Then my answer is correct for this question. Thanks for clarifying. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Define an edge $ij$ if person $i$ has worked with person $j$. Each of the $17$ adults claims to have worked with three adults. Consider the subgraph induced by the set of adults. By the handshaking lemma, it must satisfy: $\sum_{i=1}^{17} 3 = 17(3) = 2E$, a contradiction as $17(3)$ is odd.

Comment: The way I read it, each team is composed of 2 children and 3 adults, so the degree of each vertex in your adults graph would be two, not three.

Comment: Based on the OP's comment in the first post: "They all worked on the same project and they all say that they cooperated with 2 children and 3 adults", it sounds to me like each adult claims to have cooperated with three other adults. The wording is a tad ambiguous, and I could very well have misread it. :-)